# More Casual and Succinct Way to Say "John's Areas of Expertise"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am creating a user profile page, and one of the sections will contain a list of the subject areas in which the user has had the most activity and up-votes e.g. User a has **answered the most questions** and/or **received the most up-votes** in categories x, y, z. The assumption is that categories where the user answered a lot of questions and received the most up-votes would be categories in which the user has a degree of expertise.

The section will list the categories under which the user's highest percentage of the above two took place.

I am struggling to find a succinct, natural heading for this section.

I am playing around with:

1. John's Top Subjects
2. John's Areas of Expertise
3. John's Expertise

...but none of the above fit the scenario exactly, and all feel awkward and unnatural.

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: A suggestion is *specialities* or *[specialties](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/specialty)* AmE).

Comment: Realm, purview, turf. Happy hunting.

Comment: You shouldn't edit answers into the question, let them stay as answers below.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - sure, removed.

Comment: @GoDucks: You guys should have signed Selanne for another ten years.

Comment: @Rathony - description of usage is in the question - first few sentences... let me know specifically what detail would help. Expanded that part with more detail.

Comment: Looks better than before. But I am still not sure what you are looking for and why those suggested words or phrases don't work. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Why not "John's at home" or "John's strong hold?

Answer (score 3):

[*Forte*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forte?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) can do a lot of heavy lifting here:

> a person's strong suit, or most highly developed characteristic, talent, or skill; something that one excels in

Answer (score 1):

A very current idiom that is heard frequently (at least here in the US) is "wheelhouse", as in ***"that subject is in my wheelhouse"***

Dictionary.com defines the idiomatic version of [wheelhouse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wheelhouse) as follows:

> 2. in one’s wheelhouse,
>
>    a. Baseball. (of a pitch) within the zone that is most advantageous for a batter to hit a home run.
>
>    b. within one’s area of expertise or interest: "There are some subjects that are in your wheelhouse and some that are not."

Comment: It might be useful to note that this expression has nautical origins: the wheelhouse is an enclosure on a ship housing the ship's (steering) wheel.  So *in the wheelhouse* means being in control and able to affect the direction of travel.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> John's domain

A [domain](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/domain?s=t) is:

> 3. a realm or range of personal knowledge, responsibility, etc.

Or perhaps

> John's bailiwick

A [bailiwick](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bailiwick) is:

> 2. a person's area of skill, knowledge, authority, or work

Comment: Domain might be a bit ambiguous as it means multiple other things more often than this meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure that bailiwick is a common and natural word that is well known for this meaning (maybe it's just me though)

Comment: @robarwebservices it's not just you. I have *never* heard the word used in spoken language and only ever seen it written down in context a couple of times in my life.

Comment: I'll have to admit, *bailiwick* is something I've heard more from my dad and his generation. NGram confirms a tapering off. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bailiwick&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbailiwick%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbailiwick%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBailiwick%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange uses 'Activity' for this, which seems perfectly adequate.

https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76722/marv-mills?tab=topactivity

Comment: In my particular project, "Activity" is too broad. The section specifically pertains to the user's area of expertise and knowledge, and not simply the user's overall activity - which could include commenting, asking questions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. John's Virtue
2. John's Triumph
3. John's Proficiency
4. John's Effort
5. John's Performance
6. John's Attainments

Answer (score 0):

Consider, *That subject is **right up John's alley***

> right up (*or* down) someone's alley: *Fig.* ideally suited to one's interests or abilities. *Skiing is right down my alley. I love it*. *This kind of thing is right up John's alley*.

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/right+down+alley)